# Saving image data into STL file like in Matlab

Tags: opencv

I am working in OpenCV and I need to print all my triangulation mesh into STL (STereoLithography) format. I use OpenCV for my image processing. So is there a way to print in STL format in OpenCV? Matlab has it own API for STL file printing. In OpenCV I can't find API for printing in STL format. What is the best approach in OpenCV to accomplish this task? Any hint?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for STL read/write C++ code, here is the info [link](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/stla_io/stla_io.html). They are written in C++ under the under the GNU LGPL license.